# Paper size incorrect when using latex instead of pdflatex

Tags: geometry, paper-size

Somewhat opposite to other problems I found, my document size is correct when compiling with `pdflatex` but is not right when compiling with `latex`.

I'm using a custom `documentclass` [for a conference](http://eccv2014.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/eccv2014kit.tar.gz) but I don't think that is the problem. The document template provided is defining the paper size precisely with the `{geometry}` package.

This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} % define this before the line numbering.
\usepackage{ruler}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[width=122mm,left=12mm,paperwidth=146mm,height=193mm,top=12mm,paperheight=217mm]
{geometry}
```

When I compile it with `pdflatex`, I get the correct document (much smaller than A4). However, I would like to compile it with `latex` (and then do dvi->ps, ps->pdf conversion) in order to be albe to use `.eps` images.

But, when compiling with `latex` I get a smaller page embedded in an A4 with big lower and right margins. Could anybody please suggest a solution?

Comment: [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) also provides `paper=letterpaper` as an option...

Comment: @Werner I know, but this is a conference document template, not something I wrote myself, and it's mostly not a good idea to change things in the provided template if not needed.

Comment: You are setting paperwidth to 146mm in your preamble and so you should get this width with pdflatex (and no letter or a4 or something else). With latex + dvips the result depends on the config.ps. In a current texsystem you can load eps-graphics with pdflatex by using the epstopdf package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry, you're right, it's not letter size, it's just "smaller than A4". I corrected that. I will try the `epstopdf` package.

Answer (score 2):

*Too long for a comment.*

With the [files](http://eccv2014.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/eccv2014kit.tar.gz) you have provided I get:

- pdflatex: 413.858bp = 5.748in = 146mm × 615.118bp = 8.5433in = 217mm
- latex/dvips/ps2pdf: 413.86bp x 615.12bp

The only difference I see is the rounding of two decimal digits instead of three that pdflatex has used.

As expected the pages are neither in A4 or letter size, because you have specified:

`\usepackage[width=122mm,left=12mm,paperwidth=146mm,height=193mm,top=12mm,paperheight=217mm]
{geometry}`

The result, checked with `pdfinfo` is indeed 146mm × 217mm. Thus package `geometry` has done its job.

BTW, is `eccv2014kit` an ancient file, its producer entry:

```
Producer:       GNU Ghostscript 6.51
```

I found a release date for 6.60: 2000-12-31
The current version is 9.10!

Is the TeX distribution has the same age, then update, then it should work, if the correct option settings are given to `geometry`,
and the question can be closed as "off topic because of old software".

Comment: Well, I use a newer version of TeX, not from 2000. And, I just checked my papersizes: for `pdflatex` it's 5.75x8.54 inch, for `latex` it's 8.5x11 inch.

Comment: @penelope: Checked out a newer version of ghostscript? Versions of `geometry`, `dvips` are uptodate?

Comment: @penelope in older version of geometry you had to set the driver (dvips) to get correct values. And - as I wrote - the config.ps can affect page sizes:  dvips has to set them in a way that ps2pdf can't ignore them.